# #1044 - Access denied for user 'chirops0'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to transfer a site that I bought.  It comes from a different host.  I made a new data base and tried to upload the sql file.  I get this error.

Error
SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `information_schema`
--
CREATE DATABASE  `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'chirops0'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: There is a possibility that your new host doesn't allow database creation so `CREATE DATABASE` query is not allowed.

Comment: or that localhost is denied. Some, like media temple, require using the designated server name

Answer (score 2):

### It's working as it's expected to. Nothing to fix.

The `information_schema` provides access to database metadata.

[According to the documentation for MySQL 5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html):

> Each MySQL user has the right to access these tables, but can see only
>   the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user
>   has the proper access privileges.

You have *read-only* privileges depending on your access level.

> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database
>   with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not
>   perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.

Answer (score 0):

**You should only copy *your* database**, not the meta-databases that are pre-installed with MySQL. You're not allowed to copy those, and attempting to do so makes no sense.

Comment: Downvote for what reason?

Comment: upvote to counter downvote

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple just give privilege to the user to read,write etc and add that user to the database you have used.